# iAd on Xamarin iOS App

Tags: ios, xamarin, iad

I'm trying to put some IAD advertising on my Xamarin iOS App.

Googling I find out that I need the Monotouch.iAd package but I cannot find it on Xamarin Components or Nuget (or google!)

Does anybody know where I can find it? And maybe a fully working example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it is included always now,

```
using iAd;
```

You can find everything in the iAd namespace.

Comment: Had to search a bit myself too :p